# JSON, sort by totalSessionsPlayed and output top 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to sort my json by "`totalSessionsPlayed`" and then output the top 3 into my div "`show`".

I think as long as I can sort the JSON (which I have no idea how to do), I can then just output the very first 3 objects.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/wjL0wL5b/1/

```js
var homes =  [{
   "modifyDate": 1460338936000,
   "champions": [
      {
         "id": 40,
         "stats": {
            "totalDeathsPerSession": 11,
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 4,
            "totalDamageTaken": 62347,
            "totalQuadraKills": 0,
            "totalTripleKills": 0,
            "totalMinionKills": 57
           
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 75,
         "stats": {
            "totalDeathsPerSession": 6,
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
            "totalDamageTaken": 44536,
            "totalQuadraKills": 0,
            "totalTripleKills": 0,
            "totalMinionKills": 222
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 113,
         "stats": {
            "totalDeathsPerSession": 18,
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 2,
            "totalDamageTaken": 104626,
            "totalQuadraKills": 0,
            "totalTripleKills": 0,
            "totalMinionKills": 94
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 9,
         "stats": {
            "totalDeathsPerSession": 30,
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 7,
            "totalDamageTaken": 174482,
            "totalQuadraKills": 0,
            "totalTripleKills": 0,
            "totalMinionKills": 239
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 254,
         "stats": {
            "totalDeathsPerSession": 9,
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
            "totalDamageTaken": 27748,
            "totalQuadraKills": 0,
            "totalTripleKills": 0,
            "totalMinionKills": 26
         }
      }]
      }
      ];

document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=homes[0].champions[0].id + ' '+homes[0].champions[1].id+ ' '+homes[0].champions[2].id;
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: When you write JSON, what do you mean? What do you *think* JSON is?

Comment: Yeah, I realize I should use javascript but I'm crummy in it

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your object with this code:

```
homes[0].champions.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.stats.totalSessionsPlayed) - parseFloat(b.stats.totalSessionsPlayed);
});
```

For descending order, you need to switch `a.stats.totalSessionsPlayed` and `b.stats.totalSessionsPlayed`

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly.  https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/wjL0wL5b/2/ ---Updated answer